# HorizontalAlignment not working for Image inside Button (UWP)

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a button with an Image inside it

```
        <Button BorderThickness="0" Background="Black"  Grid.Column="0" Width="400" >
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="20" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/LockScreenLogo.scale-200.png" Width="20"  />
    </Button>
```

I want the image to be on the right end of the button so gave `HorizontalAlignment="Right"`. But the Image always comes in the middle of the button. How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the default style of Button, there is a **ContentPresenter** control to display the content of Button, it uses **HorizontalContentAlignment** property to control the horizontal alignment of the control's content. The default value is Center. So if you want to put the image in the right of Button, you can change the HorizontalContentAlignment to **Right**.

```
<Button HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" BorderThickness="0" Background="Black"  Grid.Column="0" Width="400" >
    <Image Height="20" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/LockScreenLogo.scale-200.png" Width="20"  />
</Button>
```